# Why is my "setter" function, stored in a std::map, not setting value correctly?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, polymorphism

I'm trying to code a basic game engine, and have been running into a problem regarding dynamic component creation. I have a minimal working example here:

```cpp
#include <bitset>
#include <variant>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

#include <iostream>

using Property = std::variant<int, unsigned int, bool, double, std::string>;

class Component
{
public:
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(Property)>> _setters;
    Component() {}

    virtual void DestroyComponent() {}
};

class Transform : public Component {
    public: static std::string name() { return "Transform"; }
    void __set_x(Property p) {
        x = std::get<double>(p);
    }
    public: double x = 0;
    
    public: Transform() {
        _setters["x"] = [=](Property p){this->__set_x(p); };
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Transform> ts = {Transform()};
    Component* c = &ts[0];

    c->_setters["x"](3.0);
    std::cout << ts[0].x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

(Note that any weirdness in terms of formatting comes from the fact that most of my components are defined with a lot of macros for convenience.)

This will end up printing `0` and returning, when it should print `3`.

Now, the problem is this: I have a list of components of a subclass (here represented as a vector of Transforms) that I need to get one of. At runtime, I don't know what the class is, so I get it by referencing the index of the element as a Component pointer. When my code calls the function linked to by `_setters[<property>]`, it does enter the function as expected (proved by putting print functions inside the lambda and called function), but the value is never set. Through debugging, I've also proved to myself that referencing the index of the vector yields the correct memory address, so the pointer should be correct. So my question is: Why aren't the values being set correctly, and how do I fix it?

Comment: `Component` should have a `virtual` destructor and `__set_x` is reserved. Don't use it. Then run with the AddressSanitizer if you have it.

Comment: `Transform` constructor inserts a lambda into `_setters`, then gets copied into the `vector`, then get destructed.  The **copy** has a lambda that has a captured `this` to the destructed `Transform`.  When that gets dereferenced, hilarity ensues.

Comment: @Eljay Hmm, that's interesting, I'm going to fiddle around with the answer you provided and see if that works any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with capturing `this` then copying your `Transform` object.

In the `Transform()` constructor the expression `_setters["x"] = [=](Property p){this->__set_x(p); };` captures `this`. This captures the immediate value `this` had when this capture occured, it can't capture the notion of "the current object".

When you construct `ts` you use an initializer list which requires the initializer to be copied. During this copy `_setters` is copied, including the setter set by the original object's default constructor. The `this` it captured still points to the original object.

Later, when you call `c->_setters["x"](3.0);` you successfully run the setter for the `Transform` pointed to by `c`, but this setter was obtained by copying another `Transform`. The setter's captured `this` still points to the original instance in the initialization list. It doesn't point to `c`. The setter is trying to set the value of `x` for an instance that no longer exists leading to Undefined Behaviour.

One possible solution is to implement a copy constructor which overwrites the `"x"` setter to capture the new instance's `this`. Example :

```
Transform(Transform const& copy) : Component(copy) {
    _setters["x"] = [=](Property p){this->__set_x(p); };
}
```

However, this solution duplicates code and may be brittle in cases where you otherwise overwrite `"x"` yourself externally. You should review your design, possibly adding a "this" parameter to your setter so any instance can pass its own `this` to the function.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem with my main program was on the same track as your answer - I needed to override the assignment operator with the lambda code. It now works like a charm!